# How to connect to SQLPLUS and run SQL script within ssh unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sqlplus

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set command "sqlplus -s user/password@tns"

ssh -t  test@192.168.94.139 $command
```

Now, I want to run te following sql script (which is on the other device I'm accessing):

```
/usr/mikael/myfile.sql
```

How is the best practice to run the script from that path?

I've seen a suggestion to add "/usr/mikael/myfile.sql" to the end of the command, as :

```
set command "sqlplus -s user/password@tns /usr/mikael/myfile.sql"
```

Is that really good? (I'm working on a prod environment and don't want to mess with it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set does not do what you think it does. Use

```
command="sqlplus -s user/password@tns @/usr/mikael/myfile.sql"
```

Comment: Thanks! good point, also for using the @ :)